# Dynamically adding rows using components into HTML table with Angular

Tags: html, angular

I'm encountering a strange problem and I cannot understand why it's happening.
I want to render an HTML table using Angular 4.

If I output the table using the following syntax everything works fine

```
<tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let athlete of athletes">
        <td></td>
        <td>{{athlete.name}}</td>
        <td>{{athlete.country}}</td>
        <td>{{athlete.time}}</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

And the table is rendered correctly:

[image]

But if do the same thing delegating the rending of the row to a component the table is not rendered correctly in Chrome (but is correct in Edge).

```
<tbody>
    <app-athlete [athlete]="athlete" *ngFor="let athlete of athletes">
    </app-athlete>
</tbody>
```

athlete.component.html

```
<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>{{athlete.name}}</td>
    <td>{{athlete.country}}</td>
    <td>{{athlete.time}}</td>
</tr>
```

[image]

Could it be due to the fact that the "rendered" DOM is something like this when looking at Google Dev tools?

[image]

I also tried putting the `<tr>` with the `*ngFor` outside of the component but the problem is always the same.

I've reproduced the problem on Plunkr: https://plnkr.co/FZAFEP5S8KhzvdKwBtbH

Comment: This is happening because the native chrome css for tables is expecting tr element to be directly under tbody. by delegating trs to a component, you introduce another tag in between. In general, try to create components that are self sufficient in terms of their rendering so you can test them seperatly. Just like you wouldn't create a component for select options, your component here should includ the whole table tags

Comment: @Mehdi so you say I should just render the whole table in one component, even if it makes the logic for both component and template much bigger? (this was just a simplified example, in reality there is quite a few logic in the rendering of the tr)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use attribute selector for your component

**athlete.component.ts**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'tr[app-athlete]',
  template: `
    <td></td>
    <td>{{athlete.name}}</td>
    <td>{{athlete.country}}</td>
    <td>{{athlete.time}}</td>
  `,
})

export class AthleteComponent {
  @Input() athlete: Athlete;
}
```

Now template of parent component should look like:

```
<tr app-athlete [athlete]="athlete" *ngFor="let athlete of athletes">
</tr>
```

**[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/EXFEV0EIg3RsnBlikDx5?p=preview)**