# Remove wrapper from Angular component

Tags: angular, components

Is it possible to add a component and keep only it's content?

Example of using a component:

```
<my-custom-component></my-custom-component>
```

This is rendered like:

```
<my-custom-component>
  <div> ... </div>
</my-custom-component>
```

Is it possible to render the content only? In this case it would be:

```
<div> ... </div>
```

I need this cause is screwing my CSS rules.

Answer (score 8):

There is feature request that looks like you want to have

- https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/22208

For now you can workaround it by using attribute selector:

```
<div myComponent> ... </div>


@Component({
  selector: '[myComponent]'
  ...
})
```

Comment: I've tried this before, `selector: '[copy-tags-button]'` and use like `<div copy-tags-button [hidden]="favoritesActionBarStatus" [tags]="favorite.tags" tags-source="Favorites" item-end></div>` but the wrapper is still there.

Comment: You can have only div on which you added attribute

Comment: I tried now again with only `<div copy-tags-button></div>`, but the content still inside the wrapper.

Comment: Content will be always inside wrapper but you can choose which wrapper it will be See similar approach. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47758430/dynamically-adding-rows-using-components-into-html-table-with-angular/47759281#47759281